# Query to retrieve info from one table and one extra col which is a condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

I have a workers table and an associated card's table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workers` (
  `ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Sname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `isAvailable` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `workers`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `cmp_idx` (`companyID`), ADD KEY `isAvailable_idx` (`isAvailable`);
```

I need to retrieve a list of workers and each one has an indicator on whether or not any of their cards have not been approved.

The cards table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cards2` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `WorkerID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `expDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reminderSent` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `regNum` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `cardType` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `approvalStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `cards2`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `cardsWorkerID_idx` (`WorkerID`);
```

The approvalStatus can be 2 (not yet determined), 1 (approved) or 2 (disapproved)
So the indicator given back should only be green(1)  if all cards are approved and red (0) if any cards are either not yet approved or disapproved.

query for retrieving workers is simply:

```
SELECT distinct Workers.ID, FName, SName, companyID
FROM Workers WHERE companyID = ? and  
and isAvailable = 1
LIMIT ?, 10
```

When attempting to get back an indicator for cards, I attempted the following:

```
    SELECT Workers.ID, FName, SName, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN approvalStatus = 0 or approvalStatus = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS cardStatus 
FROM `workers` 
inner join cards2 ON Workers.ID = Cards2.WorkerID 
WHERE workers.companyID = 1
```

This is only returning one worker however

**Update**
It should also flag up a red status if a user has no associated cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask with `EXISTS`, whether an open or disapproved card exists for a user:

```
select id, fname, sname, companyid,
  case when exists 
  (
    select * 
    from cards2 c
    where c.workerid = w.id
    and c.approvalstatus in (0,2)
  ) then then 'red' else 'green' end as status
from workers w 
where companyid = ?
and isavailable = 1;
```

UPDATE: Here is the query for the additional requirement to have no cards = red:

```
select id, fname, sname, companyid,
  case when exists 
  (
    select * 
    from cards2 c
    where c.workerid = w.id
    and c.approvalstatus in (0,2)
  )
  or not exists 
  (
    select * 
    from cards2 c
    where c.workerid = w.id
  ) then then 'red' else 'green' end as status
from workers w 
where companyid = ?
and isavailable = 1;
```

And here is the same with the statuses aggregated and using MySQL tri-boolean logic:

```
select w.id, w.fname, w.sname, w.companyid,
  case when not c.bad then 'green' else 'red' end as status
from 
(
  select 
    workerid,
    max(case when approvalstatus in (0,2) then 1 else 0 end) as bad
  from cards2
  group by workerid
) c
from workers w 
where w.companyid = ? and  
and w.isavailable = 1;
```

Comment: I have one additional requirement for the query, i just thought of also, apologies. If a user has no associated cards uploaded, that should be flagged up as red also

Comment: Easiest would be to add a `or not exists select * from cards2 c where c.workerid = w.id` of course.

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried out your last approach and receive the following error 'MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by workerid'

Comment: Oops, the FROM clause was missing. Sorry. I've corrected this now.

Comment: yeah i had spotted that and thought it may have been the issue but when I added it in, I got the error: 'MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from workers w'

Comment: if you happen to get a chance, I haven't had any responses on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989107/php-binding-dynamic-number-of-variables-for-batch-insert-query